# Yeoman pass prompt answers to subgenerator

Tags: yeoman, yeoman-generator

I have a yeoman generator with some subgenerators.

I know I can pass options from the parent- to the subgenerators when calling `composeWith(...).`

But how can I pass the answers I get from prompting? The are not available at the point when composeWith is called.

For example I prompt in the generator for an app name and want to provide this to all the subgenerators as options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh, found in the related questions that I could call the subgenerator after prompting, instead of the initialize-method (as in the quite outdated tutorial)

Answer (score 1):

One way to do this is using the [built-in config](https://yeoman.io/authoring/storage.html).

In the "parent" generator:

```
configuring(){
    this.log('Saving configuration in .yo-rc.json')
    const answers = this.answers.answers()
    for(const key in answers){
        this.config.set(key, answers[key])
    }
    this.config.save()
}
```

In the "child" generator, to populate templates:

```
    const templateData = {
        ...this.config.getAll(),
        ...
    }
    this.fs.copyTpl(
        this.templatePath(),
        this.destinationPath(),
        templateData
    )
```

This should be simple enough to change for your use case, eg perhaps you'd want `this.config.get(something)` in the child generator.

Just note this won't work across *different* generators; only between a generator and its *own* sub-generators:

> The .yo-rc.json file is a JSON file where configuration objects from multiple generators are stored. Each generator configuration is namespaced to ensure no naming conflicts occur between generators.
>
> This also means each generator configuration is sandboxed and can only be shared between sub-generators. You cannot share configurations between different generators using the storage API. Use options and arguments during invocation to share data between different generators.